# Compare dates in excel, then execute logic based on results

Tags: excel

I am trying to compare only the day portion of a date in Excel and then sum all the columns that contain that date on another sheet. So if it is the 5th, I need to sum all the values that were logged on the 5th and then sum those values. The date may need to be parsed out but I think I have that down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array `Sum` formula with a nested `If` statement.
The date function extract the day number ( `Day(8/21/2018) = 21` )

> =SUM(IF(DAY(`DateRange`) = `TargetDay`, `SumRange`, ""))

Where:
`DateRange` = The range that has your dates
`TargetDay` = The day you want to sum for (5 in your example)
`SumRange` = The range that has the corrosponding values to be summed

Since this is an **Array** formula, you will need to type in the above equation and hit  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>Enter</kbd>  for this to work. After, your formula should show enclosed in `{ }` as seen in the below photo

---

[image]

Comment: Hell, yes, that works exactly like I need it to. Thank you so much!